# cmd line prompt for navigating to only folder in current folder. Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, navigation, directory, prompt

Suppose I have a folder called Documents, with only one folder inside, called Projects, as illustrated incredibly below...

```
Documents

    Projects
```

If I'm in Documents, is there a cmd line prompt which will take me into the only available folder, in this case Projects?

So instead of using

```
cd Projects
```

I'm looking for

```
cd 'only available folder'
```

Is there a cmd for this?

In response to an answer which was deleted: I'm not looking for a list of folder contents. I'm looking to navigate directly into the only available folder.

I suppose one option is:

```
cd 'Tab button'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a simple command for this.  Like you suggested, the best solution, and what I would do, is `cd`<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.  Strictly speaking, there is a command that satisfies your requirements, but it's not exactly easy under the fingers.

```
for /d %I in (*) do cd "%I"
```

which would loop through all directories in the current directory (ostensibly, only one), then `cd` to it.